# how to connect to blockchain via etherscan provider

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, etherscan

Hello i am trying to connect to the ethereum network with etherscan as HTTP provider so users don't have to have a running node but i cant seem to find their provider-URL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they have a provider available still, but [Alchemy](https://alchemy.com/?a=016d67c4f7) is a good alternative.

You just sign up for an account, create an app, and then view key:

[image: how to find Alchemy API key]

Answer (score 0):

The provider is still available,

1. You choose a plan [here](https://etherscan.io/apis)
2. Once you have an account on your https://etherscan.io/myapikey you will see the API key menu.
3. Create one.
4. To connect with your application you can follow the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-providers.html) which includes how to connect to both Etherscan and INFURA.

Basically you just need this line of code:
`new ethers . providers . EtherscanProvider( [ network = “homestead” ] [ , apiToken ] )`